# JAVA - Should I set null to every instanciated object after using it?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I have a doubt about Java Garbage Collector. Just to illustrate, I have a json like this:

```
List<Test_DTO> testes = new ArrayList();
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

for (Test_DTO test : testes) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    if(test != null) 
        obj.put("codigo",""+test .getCodigo());

    list.put(obj);
}

list = null;
```

Am I supposed to set `list = null` in the end of my file so that the Collector can "clean" it out? If so, should I set `obj = null` inside the `for` after `list.put(obj);`? Or does (the cleaning) happen automatically? This question is not specific to this example, as I said, it was just to make it clearer to understand.

Thanks in advance,

Lucas.

Comment: If you're done with `list` at the end of that code, then what's the point of the code? All it seems to do is populate `list`...

Comment: Don't do that. It _may_ have been of some use 15+ years ago, but today, it does nothing but add clutter to the code (and prevents a lot of legitimate uses of `final` as well).

Comment: This is not the point of my question.. Actually, there're tons of line codes before list = null

Comment: This _is_ the point. Tons of codes or not, don't do that. The GC is smarter than you. Really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I supposed to set `list = null` in the end of my file so that the Collector can "clean" it out?

There's no need provided the code you've quoted is in a method and `list` is a local variable within the method. When the method returns, the local variables are destroyed, and if nothing else has a reference to the object(s) those variables referred to, the objects become available for garbage collection.

If `list` isn't a local variable within a method, it probably should be. :-)

Note, though, that there seems little point to that code if you're not using `list` once you're done populating it, as that's all that code does. If you're assigning `list` to something else when you're done (putting it on an object as a property, etc.), then there's still no need to set `list` to `null`, but the *reason* there's no need changes: If you're saving the list that `list` refers to somewhere else, then the list will have an outstanding reference, and it won't be eligible for garbage collection (whether you set `list` to `null` or not).

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer. One last thing: if this code is inside a .jsp file, the variables are recognized as local variables?

Comment: @lucasdc: It depends on where in the JSP they are. If they're within a `<% ... %>` block, then yes, they end up being local variables inside a method in the generated servlet class.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to set it to null. The garbage collector will take care of it.
Take a look here for better understanding.
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.

If the code you pasted is for example a part of loop in thread that runs once per hour or a long living object's property than it is good to set `null` to the `list` reference and allow GC to trash `JSONArray`.

But **in most cases you do not have to worry about it**.

Answer (score 0):

When creating bitmaps, Android often fails with out of memory errors, and does not try to garbage collect first. Hence, call System.gc(), and you have enough memory to create Bitmaps.

**If creating Objects, I think System.gc will be called automatically** if needed, but not for creating bitmaps. It just fails.

So I recommend manually calling System.gc() before creating bitmaps.

Comment: Calling `System.gc()` is only **suggestion** for JVM to start garbage collector process.

Comment: System.gc() don't guarantee tht it will clean the heap at that time.

Comment: and its needed only before creating bitmaps otherwise its called automatically.